# How to access a method in the type class of an ObservableList (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, methods, observablelist

I have an `ObservableList` of type Part that holds several Part objects. When adding a new Part to the ObservableList, I want to check to see if the value of a variable partID is equal to the value of the same variable partID in other Parts. Here is how I have my code set up now:

```
public class Inventory {
     public static ObservableList<Part> allParts = 
     FXCollections.observableArrayList();

     public static ObservableList<Part> getAllParts() {
          return allParts;
     }
}

public abstract class Part {
     public final IntegerProperty partID;

     public Part(int partID) {
          this.partID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(partID);
     }

     public void setPartID(int partID) {
          this.partID.set(partID);
     }
     public int getPartID() {
          return partID.get();
     }
}
```

Now, in my FXML controller, I have the following code where I attempt to take the text field of a new partID and check to see if any other existing partID already contains the same value, so that I can inform the user to choose a new partID if it does, or add the new part if it doesn't.

```
@FXML
void AddPartSaveButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
     if(partIDTextField.getText() != null) {
          String partIDString = partIDTextField.getText();
          int partID = Integer.parseInt(partIDString);

          if(partID != Inventory.getAllParts().getPartID() { 
               //getPartID() is redlined
               Inventory.getAllParts().add(newPart);
          }
     }
 }
```

The compiling error obviously occurs when attempting to call getPartID() from getAllParts(), since it is not an instance of it. So how can I access all of the existing partIDs from allParts?

PS - partID is not the only variable being held in the ObservableList. I have many others (like partName, partPrice, etc.), but figured they aren't relevant to the core of the question.

Comment: Java 8 allows you to do this: `Inventory.getAllParts().stream().noneMatch(part -> part.getPartId() == partID)`. In java 7 you need to search the list the way James_D describes it in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option is to iterate through the list and see if any existing part ids match (note I have changed some names of variables and methods to conform to proper naming conventions):

```
@FXML
void addPartSaveButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
     if(partIDTextField.getText() != null) {
          String partIDString = partIDTextField.getText();
          int partID = Integer.parseInt(partIDString);


          boolean hasMatch = false ;
          for (Part part : inventory.getAllParts()) {
              if (part.getPartID() == partID) {
                  hasMatch = true ;
                  break ;
              }
          }
          if (! hasMatch) { 
               //getPartID() is redlined
               Inventory.getAllParts().add(newPart);
          }
     }
 }
```

You could use streams to make this code a little slicker (though it is essentially doing exactly the same thing):

```
@FXML
void addPartSaveButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
     if(partIDTextField.getText() != null) {
          String partIDString = partIDTextField.getText();
          int partID = Integer.parseInt(partIDString);


          boolean noneMatch = inventory.getAllParts().stream()
              .mapToInt(Part::getPartID)
              .noneMatch(id -> id == partID);

          if (noneMatch) { 
               //getPartID() is redlined
               Inventory.getAllParts().add(newPart);
          }
     }
 }
```

If performance is an issue (you are iterating through the entire list every time you add a new element, which could be problematic if you add many elements), then you should keep the ids in a separate data structure which is faster to search. E.g.:

```
private Set<Integer> partIDs = new HashSet<>();

// ...

inventory.getAllParts().addListener((Change<? extends Part> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            for (Part part : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                partIDs.add(part.getPartID());
            }
        }
        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            for (Part part : c.getRemoved()) {
                partIDs.remove(part.getPartID());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and then

```
@FXML
void addPartSaveButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
     if(partIDTextField.getText() != null) {
          String partIDString = partIDTextField.getText();
          int partID = Integer.parseInt(partIDString);

          if (! partIDs.contains(partID)) { 
               //getPartID() is redlined
               Inventory.getAllParts().add(newPart);
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Your first solution worked like a charm.